# Why I am getting function not defined on DOM object conversion to jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

The code:

```
(function ($) {

    console.log($.fn.jquery, 'version'); //1.4.4
    //elements is an array of dom elements (div)
    var attachAppearListener = function(elements) {
        $.each(elements, function() {
           //this.contructor is [object XrayWrapper function HTMLDivElement() { [native code] }]
            $(this).find('.ebep-stream-item-id').on('appear', function(event, $all_appeared_elements) {
                console.log($all_appeared_elements);
            });
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

debug of `this.constructor` gives me:

> [object XrayWrapper function HTMLDivElement

in FireBug console.

The error is:

> TypeError: $(...).find(...).on is not a function

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `elements` what is it? if you could explain bit more about it.

Comment: Did you include jQuery, and what version ?

Comment: Where are you invoking that? In the .each iterator function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TypeError: $(...).find(...).on is not a function

Update your jQuery to something from this decade.  `.on()` was not added until 1.7 so you're calling on a method that doesn't exist in 1.4.4.

### [jQuery .on() API page](http://api.jquery.com/on/)